# Issue while reading a csv file through Spark

Tags: json, scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a csv file through Spark. However one of the columns has the data in the below format and because of comma it is being split into multiple columns. The input csv file is a comma delimited file.

```
"[{"code": "100", "name": "CLS1", "type": "PRIMARY"}]"
```

could you please help me how to parse this column in spark scala.

I tried using option("escape","") and option("quoteMode","ALL"). didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read directly such column using Spark CSV reader, as there is no way to distinguish between a comma that is part of the json string and a column-separator, and you can't use `"` as quote character for the same reason.

To solve this, you should read your CSV file as a text file, split `String` rows to a `Seq[String]` and then recreate columns from this `Seq[String]`

For instance, if you have a file called `file.csv` with the following content:

```
column1, column2, column3, column4
1, "value1", "[{"code": "100", "name": "CLS1", "type": "PRIMARY"}]", 1.1
2, "value2", "[{"code": "200", "name": "CLS2", "type": "SECONDARY"}]", 1.2
```

Your Spark program would be:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import sparkSession.implicits._

val finalDataframe = sparkSession.read.text("file.csv")
  .filter(col("value").notEqual("column1, column2, column3, column4"))
  .as[String]
  .map(splitRow)
  .withColumn("column1", col("value").getItem(0).cast("int"))
  .withColumn("column2", col("value").getItem(1).cast("string"))
  .withColumn("column3", col("value").getItem(2).cast("string"))
  .withColumn("column4", col("value").getItem(3).cast("float"))
  .drop("value")
```

Where `splitRow` function takes a `String` as input and returns `Seq[String]`, each `String` in sequence representing a column value.

A implementation of this method could be:

```scala
def splitRow(row: String): Seq[String] = row.foldLeft(Accumulator())((acc, char) => char match {
  case ',' if !acc.openBracket => acc.copy(result = acc.buffer +: acc.result, buffer = "", previousIsHyphen = false)
  case '[' if acc.previousIsHyphen => acc.copy(buffer = "[", openBracket = true, previousIsHyphen = false)
  case '"' if !acc.openBracket => acc.copy(previousIsHyphen = true)
  case '"' if acc.buffer.last == ']' => acc.copy(openBracket = false)
  case _ => acc.copy(buffer = acc.buffer + char, previousIsHyphen = false)
}).flush()
```

With the following case class as `Accumulator`:

```scala
case class Accumulator(
  result: Seq[String] = Nil, 
  openBracket: Boolean = false, 
  buffer: String = "", 
  previousIsHyphen: Boolean = false
) {
  def flush(): Seq[String] = (buffer +: result).reverse
}
```

If we use this code, we obtain the following output when parsing `file.csv`:

```
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3                                               |column4|
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|1      | value1|[{"code": "100", "name": "CLS1", "type": "PRIMARY"}]  |1.1    |
|2      | value2|[{"code": "200", "name": "CLS2", "type": "SECONDARY"}]|1.2    |
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this whole string is value of just one field inside of csv file. In that case you should use some of the Spark options `quote` and/or `quteMode`.

I'm not 100% on this one but I think that `quote` takes string representation of the quote that is going to be used inside of csv and `quoteMode` seems to depends on the version because they switched the library at some point. On 3.x it should be just `true` or `false` and in below version there should be options like [these](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/QuoteMode.html) available.

Anyways, you'll have to play with it a little bit, it's more of a direction than answer, but I hope it helps because I don't have time to test it right now.